# In ORACLE SQL, there is a problem with comparing 2 string ('E' > 'e' says true)

Tags: sql, string, oracle, compare, sql-injection

currently, I'm studying SQL injection on SQL DBMS on WebSecurityAcademy(https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/blind), especially about blind SQL-injection using conditional responses. First, the target website look like the picture below
[Sorry for not being able to post the image... Click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29wJb.png)

Now,  there is a cookie provided by the webserver called **TrackingId (It seems to be a session cookie with random value)**, and I used this cookie for Blind SQL injection.

At first time, I input `1' OR 2=1 -- %20` for **TrackingId** cookie value. And after reloading the page, there was nothing changed, so I modify the cookie value with `1' OR 1=1 -- %20`. And  after reloading it, I could see the web page output 'Welcome!!'

So, I concluded that the SQL query for **TrackingId** would be like `SELECT ... FROM User WHERE TrackingId='{injection point}' ...`. *(Well, just ignore about table name User and column name TrackingId... it is just a guess)*

After that, I tried to get the password of the administrator (there is username = 'administrator' in the `users` table... It was given..) by using the **substring** function in ORACLE(I concluded that DBMS is ORACLE because it can concatenate the string with '||' operator).

Before tryout, I input `1' OR 'E'>'e` (just for testing) for **TrackingId** Cookie, expecting  it would return false (For ASCII Value, 'E' <'e'). But, after reloading the page, the web page output 'Welcome!!' for 'E' >'e' condition being true!!!

I'm so confused with it. As far as I know, in ORACLE comparison of strings is based on ASCII value... But, Why 'E' <'e' condition holds true ????

- I tried 'D' <'e' also later, and it says it is true
- I tried 'F' > 'e' also, and it says it is false
- I tried 'E' = 'e' also, and it says it is false

So, in conclusion, it says  'D'<'e' != E<'F' ???? How does this can happen???

**Here are some sample pictures**

- [First Cookie Value injection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoLbh.png) and
  [Result of injection-Success!! (Meaning 'e' <'K' Holds True)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwdCR.png)
- [Second Cookie Value injection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7j0I.png) and
  [Result of injection-Success!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igIPk.png) and
- [Third Cookie Value injection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2nwk.png) and
  [Result of injection-Success(Meaning 'e' > 'A Holds True..)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swZWx.png)

Comment: Well as you state, the comparison is based on ASCII and the ASCII code for `E` (069) is in fact lower than `e` (101).

Comment: Your title says ''E' > 'e' says true"; your question text seems to be confusing the logic: "after reloading the page ... 'E' <'e' condition being true" and "Why 'E' <'e' condition holds true". So it isn't clear what you're actually testing or seeing. (All the injection stuff is irrelevant - you can demonstrate this with direct queries against dual, and changing nls_comp/nls_sort, though I can't see a combination that would match the title and the three bullets.)

Comment: As stated in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-A114F1F4-A08D-4107-B679-323DC7FEA31C): *In binary collation, which is the default, Oracle compares character values like binary values*. To see binary values you may use `select dump('e', 16) as "e", dump('E', 16) as "E" from dual`: bytes will be shown after `len=..:`. Comparison of ASCII codes is the result of the fact that most codepages cover ASCII at the first 128 points

Comment: Sorry for confusing you... I edited question... from 'E' <'e' condition being true to 'E' >'e' condition being true...

Comment: If you're ok, I will post my picture about it

Comment: @Woo - 'E'>'e' and 'D' < 'e' being true, and your latest edit with 'e'<'K', 'e<J' and 'e'>'A' all being true, could all be explained by the DB session having nls_comp=LINGUISTIC and nls_sort being maybe KOREAN_M, picked up from your browser territory, at a guess (which also makes 'E'='e' false); but I can't see how to make all those things true and also have 'F'>'e' false. Maybe the DB sessions were different, or your description is still confused. A table showing the conditions you applied, whether you expected each to be true or false, and whether they actually were, might be clearer.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results when tested in one session the following examples work as expected `select count(*) from dual where 'D' < 'e';
select count(*) from dual where 'F' > 'e';
select count(*) from dual where 'E' = 'e';`